# Firebase Functions How to remove node from realtime database and file from storage after certain time

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm a newbie in the use of Firebase Functions. 

After 7 days (calculated by a timestamp) I would like to remove a Post node from my database and, after that, remove all nodes form Comment and Reaction that have a reference to that post. After that if photoVideoPath of the post is a reference of firebase Storage, I want to remove that object from my storage.
My database structure is:

```
Post: {
       PostKey: {
                 date: xx/xx/xxxx
                 timestamp: xxxxxxxx
                 photoVideoPath: xxxxxxxxxx
                 title: xxxxxxxxxxx
                }
        [...]
       }

Comment: {
           PostKey: {
                      date: xx/xx/xx
                      hours: xx:xx
                      user: idUser
                      text: xxxxxxxxxx
                     }
           [...]
         }

Reaction: {
            PostKey: {
                       type: xxxxxx
                       user: idUser
                     }
             [...]
           }
```

and the code I've wrote is:

```
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/Post/{pushId}').onWrite((change) => {
    const ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent
    const now = Date.now();
    const cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;
    ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff).once('value', res => {
        // create a map with all children that need to be removed
        const updates = {};
        res.forEach(child => {
            updates[child.key] = null;
        });

        ref.update(updates);

        functions.database.ref('/Reaction/').child(res.key).remove();
        functions.database.ref('/Comment/').child(res.key).remove();

        if (!res.val().photoVideoPath.startsWith("data:image/") && !res.val().photoVideoPath.startsWith("http")) {
            const filePath = res.val().title + res.val().data.replace("/", "").replace("/", "") + res.val().photoVideoPath
            const bucket = googleCloudStorage.bucket('xxxxxxx.appspot.com')
            const file = bucket.file(filePath)

            file.delete().then(() => {
                return console.log(`Successfully deleted photo`)
            }).catch(err => {
                return console.log(`Failed to remove photo, error: ${err}`)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

what am I doing wrong? Thanks to all and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You're not paying attention to the promises returned by update() and remove().  Also, you're not working with the promise returned by delete() correctly.  Realtime Database trigger functions must return a promise that resolves only when all the other asynchronous work in the function is complete.

To learn more about how to use promises with Cloud Functions, consider following the tutorials here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I've tried to use the async/await struct in my function but unfortunatly it gives me an error. I've found that the problem is the ECMA Version so I've changed in the .eslintrc.json file that version ("parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2017
  },) but I have not solved the problem. Do you  have any advice? (I'm sorry to bother you.)